# MVC onfocusout event not firing

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Im getting confused about the onfocusout event in my mvc view.

```
<div class="editor-field" id="supplieridentificationID" >
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SupplierIdentification)
</div>
<div id="suppliername" class="editor-label" />
```

And my javascript code:

```
$('#supplieridentificationID').onfocusout(function () { alert("ajax here!" })
```

I cant get this to work, actually im trying to send the SupplierIdentification to my controller and get the Json with the SupplierName and put on "suppliername" label.
All using onfocusout function with the ajax.

Any sugestions?

EDIT:

I tried other code, and still not getting nothing:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Novo Documento</legend>

     <div class="editor-field" id="ident">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SupplierIdentification)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ident').focusin(function () { alert("focusin"); });
});
```

Comment: What does the resulting client-side HTML look like?  If `Html.EditorFor()` uses the property name as the element's `id` then you're re-using `id` attributes which is invalid markup.  Also, check for errors on the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) instead of `onfocusout`

```
$('#SupplierIdentification').focusout(function() { alert("ajax here!" });
```

Comment: Nothing, i really cant get the alert message when i click outside.

Comment: @ggui: Have you replaced `supplieridentificationID` by `SupplierIdentification` on your jquery selector?

Comment: yes Claudio, I did it. Do you have any other approach to do that? It is simple, but i cant make it work. If I call a function inside the <div> it works. But i dont have focusout function inside the div. I just want to send the value wich user put on the supplieridentificationID editor to the controller.

Comment: @ggui you do have the code wrapped around `$( document ).ready()`, right?

Comment: @ggui Can you paste the rendered HTML and the JavaScript so we can see how everything is put together? Also, are you seeing any error in the debug console?

Answer (score 0):

try  adding an id to control so you can reference it in Jquery.

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SupplierIdentification, new { @id = "id"})`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#id').blur(function () {
   alert("focusin");
   });
});
```

blur function happens when element loses focus